# How can I trigger the "autocomplete" event in the jQuery Autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to trigger the jQuery Autocomplete event externally. The problem is I'm using

```
/*
 * Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.0.2
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Dylan Verheul, Dan G. Switzer, Anjesh Tuladhar, Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js 5747 2008-06-25 18:30:55Z joern.zaefferer $
 *
 */
```

If I upgrade, I need to find something that's a DIRECT drop in because it's old legacy code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean trigger the auto complete event externally? You want to send a request to the server? Or you want to fill it in with your data that's not from the server you're querying?

Comment: When I paste, nothing happens. It simple erases the textbox.

Comment: Please put that in the description, it seems like a big part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the source code. There's a function called: onChange that you want to call like onChange(0,true) to trigger the autocomplete. I don't think it's accessible from outside the script code though, so you can either expose the function globally or you can edit the autocomplete code to listen for a paste event on the input and onChange(0,true).